# SAS: Numbers with a minimum of two decimal points

Tags: sas, format, numbers

I want to display numbers in SAS this way, with two decimal points minimum:

1   -> 1.00

1/2 -> 0.50

1/3 -> 0.3333333333

1/4 -> 0.25

1/5 -> 0.20

This needs to be a format. How is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to store numbers or store a character representation of the number?  If you are storing numbers then the format used to display them should not really matter very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom format that relies on a user defined function created by `Proc FCMP`.

Example:

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.functions.formats; 
  function egad(x) $;
    length result $50;
    result = putn(x,'best12.');
    p = index(result,'.');
    if p then do;
      if substr(result,p+1,1)=' ' then result=cats(result,'00');
      else
      if substr(result,p+2,1)=' ' then result=cats(result,'0');
    end;
    else
      result=cats(result,'.00');

    return (result);
  endsub;
run;

options cmplib=work.functions;

proc format;
  value egad (default=12) other=[egad()];


* verify that both the function and format are working; 
data _null_;
  x = 1/3;
  s = egad(x);
  t = put(x,egad.);
  put x= s= t=;
  run;
```

Comment: Hi @Richard, thanks, this helped a lot! But what happens when other people open this database and they don't know what "egad" is? Do they get an error message?

Comment: Edag: As SAS does not have a built-in format for this, if you share this dataset, you will need to include Richard's code to generate the format as well. If this is not feasible, an alternative would be to save the formatted value in a character variable (i.e xChar=put(x,egad.);) and include xChar in your shared dataset.

Comment: Using a format does not change the underlying value.  Other clients viewing the data set will need the format available to their session via being explicitly defined for that session (by running the `Proc FORMAT` code) or the format is accessible via the `options FMTSEARCH=` catalog specification.  If not available, a SAS session can use `options NOFMTERR` to prevent errors when an unknown format is called out.